# How to create multi auth in laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I used to be for laravel 5.5 and earlier than https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth .

But this repository don't update for laravel 5.6.

How to create multi auth in Laravel 5.6?

Comment: There is very nice post related to this topic. Step by step process to create Multi Auth in Laravel. https://www.gautammenariya.com/2018/11/set-up-multiple-authentication-in.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After lots of digging and lots of questions & answers I have finally managed to work Laravel 5.6 Multi Auth with two table, So I'm writing Answer of my own Question.

**How to implement Multi Auth in Larvel**

As Mentioned above.
Two table `admin` and `users`

Laravel 5.2 has a new `artisan` command.

`php artisan make:auth`

it will generate basic login/register `route`, `view` and `controller` for `user` table.

Make a `admin` table as `users` table for simplicity.

**Controller For Admin**
`app/Http/Controllers/AdminAuth/AuthController`
`app/Http/Controllers/AdminAuth/PasswordController`
(note: I just copied these files from `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController` here)

**`config/auth.php`**

```
//Authenticating guards
'guards' => [
    'user' =>[
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'user',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],  

//User Providers
'providers' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ]
],  

//Resetting Password  
'passwords' => [
    'clients' => [
        'provider' => 'client',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

**`route.php`**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //Login Routes...
    Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('/admin/logout','AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@register');

    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');

});
```

**`AdminAuth/AuthController.php`**

Add two methods and specify `$redirectTo` and `$guard`

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
protected $guard = 'admin';
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if (view()->exists('auth.authenticate')) {
        return view('auth.authenticate');
    }

    return view('admin.auth.login');
}
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('admin.auth.register');
}
```

it will help you to open another login form for admin

**creating a middleware for `admin`**

```
class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
{
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

}

register middleware in `kernel.php`

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
];
```

use this middleware in `AdminController` 
e.g.,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('admin');
   }
public function index(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

That's all needed to make it working and also to get json of authenticated admin use
 `Auth::guard('admin')->user()`

We can access authenticated user directly using
`Auth::user()`
but if you have two authentication table then you have to use

```
Auth::guard('guard_name')->user()
```

for logout

```
Auth::guard('guard_name')->user()->logout()
```

for authenticated user json

```
Auth::guard('guard_name')->user()
```

Comment: This answer would be a lot more helpful if it explained what exactly these changes are doing...

Comment: You haven't added anything about model?

Comment: Also Please Explain Illuminate\Foundations\Auth\User?
What is this?