# multi auth laravel 5.6 step by step for beginner

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.6

can someone help me how to make multi auth in laravel 5.6, i have read this [How to create multi auth in laravel 5.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49315781/how-to-create-multi-auth-in-laravel-5-6)
but still cant understand. pls help me.

Comment: Hello and welcome, maybe this can help: https://hackernoon.com/laravel-multiple-authentication-80daa855322b

Comment: what a diffrent of multi auth laravel 5.5 and 5.6 ?

Comment: not much different, maybe before you go and try, learn about middlewares and how to create auth system, then try the multi auth thing

Comment: thanks man, i learn it first

Answer (score 1):

This guy rocks...I learned how to do multi auth with this youtube video, it's little bit long but it will surely get you to making authentication for both Admin and User if that's what you want.

### https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKRLrJXNN4M&list=PLwAKR305CRO9S6KVHMJYqZpjPzGPWuQ7Q

This is a cheat sheet I made for this tutorial video. Reference it when you get too tired of typing everything on the video. However, I strongly recommend watch the video, just looking at these instructions might be not enough.

**Basic Auth & Admin Model**

```
php artisan make:auth

php artisan make:migration create_admins_table --create=admins
```

> database/migrations/???_create_admins_table.php

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Duplicate User model to Admin model**

User.php

Admin.php

**Make guard for Admin in auth.php**

> config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'admin-api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
**Create provider for Admin**
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ]
],
**Create password resets for admin**
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

**Applying Admin Guard to admin Model**

> App/Admin.php

```
protected $guard = 'admin’;
```

**Make AdminContoller**

Duplicate HomeController -> AdminController

> App/Http/Controllers/AdminController.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');
}
```

**Make AdminLoginController**

```
php artisan make:controller Auth/AdminLoginController
```

**Make Admin Login view**

Duplicate login.blade.php -> admin-login.blade.php

resources/views/admin-login.blade.php

**Login -> Admin Login**

```
route(‘login’) -> route(‘admin.login.submit’)
```

**Admin Route Setting**

> routes/web.php

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index’)->name(‘admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
});
```

**Make AdminLoginController login**

> app/http/controllers/Auth/AdminLoginController.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => ['logout']]);
}

public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.admin-login');
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    // Validate the form adata
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    //Attempt to log the user in
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
        //if sucessful, the redirect to their
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
    }
    //if unseccessful
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}

public function logout()
{
    Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

**Resolving redirection error 1**

- error when /admin leads to /login
- Solve it using Exception Handler. In state of unauthenticated, when guard is admin, redirect it to /admin/login, in other case, redirect it to /login

> App/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'unauthenticated'], 401);
    }

    $guard = array_get($exception->guards(),0);

    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            $login = 'admin.login';
            break;
        default:
            $login = 'login';
            break;
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route($login));
}
```

**Resolving redirection error 2**

- Page protected by guest middleware only leads to /home
- When logged in as a user, entering /admin will redirect to /home, it is a caused due to only recognizing guest:user. Therefore, we should fix RedirectIfAuthenticated so that our application can recognize guest:admin , too.

> App/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
            }
            break;
        default:
            if(Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect()->route('/home');
            }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**Update config cache of your laravel project**

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: i have wacth it, that is for laravel 5.4, but i try again, hope it works :). thanks man