# Laravel RedirectIfAuthenticated Not Working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a **company** guard.

When I logged in with the company auth. I can still access the routes that I have provided guest middleware. Example *login* and *register* routes.

I have given guest middleware but it still doesn't work.

I think the problem is in the "*RedirectIfAuthenticated.php*" file.

**route file**

```
Route::namespace('Auth')->middleware('guest')->group(function ()
{
    
    Route::view('login', 'company.auth.login');
    Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login');
    Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
    
    Route::view('register', 'company.auth.register');
    Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register')->name('register');

});
```

**RedirectIfAuthenticated File**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if ($guard == 'company' && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('company/home');
    }
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**auth config file**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'company' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'companies'
    ]
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Student::class,
    ],

    'companies' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Company::class
    ]
],
```

***Help Me Bro***

Comment: perhaps you want to pass the guard name as a parameter for that middleware

Comment: I think the question will help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49315781/how-to-create-multi-auth-in-laravel-5-6